# How does XGboost (Python) differentiate between a nominal variable and a continuous variable?

Tags: categorical-data, cart, boosting

Assume the data in one dimension is (-1.0, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 5.0). Does [XGboost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost) regard it as a nominal or a continuous variable?

Comment: How does the body of this question relate to the title?  Are there actually two questions here?

Comment: @MatthewDrury I only give 5 numbers but do not say whether they are samples from a continuous distribution or just 5 elements of a nominal attribute. The question is how will XGboost treat them?

Comment: Ohhhh.  Hahah.  I read "differentiate" as "take the derivative of".  I understand now!  I added the word "between" to your title to make the intent clear.

Comment: @HuayuZhang do you use the R wrapper to it?

Comment: @air No. I use python.

Comment: @HuayuZhang ah sorry, then I cannot help you. In R you'd usually specify a nominal variable by using the appropriate data-type, i.e. use a factor rather than Float64 for your data vector.

Comment: A continuous variable. The categorical features must do one hot encoding before put into the model.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on the last sentence a little... as it is written, it's not clear what it means to anyone unfamiliar with what "hot encoding" means (like me.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be arbitrary, for example the the [XBGClassifier fit()](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py) routine takes X to be an array like feature matrix.

Comment: How does XGBClassifier make a split when learning the tree? I think the criteria for the nominal and the numeric are different.

Comment: @HuayuZhang: The current implementation of XGBoost supports only numeric data not factors. Here's the reference for the R package (I presume Python is similar): http://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/R-package/discoverYourData.html

In either case, the distinction hardly matters for splits. You can read the details about splits here: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.02754v1.pdf

but the short answer is that splits are calculated using percentiles that group the data. For binary features, this will translate to how many features are 0 vs 1, hence the actual split location in (0,1) is irrelevant.